# Android Log in with CheckBox

Tags: android

My first application in android studio and i want to do this:

**Description:**

username:username (TextBox)

password:password (TextBox)

Keep me logged in -->CheckBox

LOGIN -->BUTTON

The first time where the user enters your username and password and click to Keep me logged in the application must be remember the username and password without the user writes again  in the second time.

Could anyone give me some idea how this implement in android, I found many examples but nothing work.

Answer (score 0):

You could use SharedPreferences to remember the user preference. Here it is a boolean.

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
boolean keepLoggedIn = prefs.getBoolean(KEY_KEEP_LOGGED_IN, false);

//After user makes the selection on the checkbox,
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit();
editor.putBoolean(KEY_KEEP_LOGGED_IN, true);
editor.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

I did something very similar to this recently

First, make sure to initialize your fields in question

```
AutoCompleteTextView mEmailView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.email);
EditText mPasswordView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
Button mEmailSignInButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.email_sign_in_button);
```

Set your onClick event:

```
mEmailSignInButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            attemptLogin();
        }
    });
```

In order for the user password to be remembered, you have to save them somewhere. I stored them in shared preferences, but you can use a more secure method depending on your application or even encrypt before storing them http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref

```
//Initialize the shared preferences, set in private mode
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("userDetails", MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
//Put the strings in the editor
editor.putString(getString(R.string.userAccount), email);
editor.putString(getString(R.string.password), password);
```

Now in onCreate or your other favorite android start method (depending on if you're using a fragment or activity), retrieve them

```
//Initialize the shared preferences, set in private mode
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("userDetails", MODE_PRIVATE);
//Retrive the values
sharedPref.getString(getString(R.string.userAccount), "")
sharedPref.getString(getString(R.string.password), "")
```